# What seems to be the problem? Sorry im new with this

Tags: mysql, wampserver

Im just testing things out but my first code didnt work.

```
CREATE TABLE `Accounts`.`Registry` ( `Username` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL ,
                                     `Password` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL ,
                                     `First Name` INT(20) NOT NULL , 
                                     `Last Name` INT(20) NOT NULL , 
                                     `Gender` INT(1) NOT NULL , 
                                     `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
PRIMARY KEY (`Password`, `First Name`, `Last Name`), 
UNIQUE (`ID`(1000)),
UNIQUE (`Username`)) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

**Error**

`#089 - Incorrect prefix key, the used length is longer than the key part, or the storage engine doesnt support unique prefix keys`

Comment: Why you have mentioned ```UNIQUE (`ID` (1000))```  try removing that to work use ```UNIQUE (`ID`)```

Comment: I see multiple potential problems here, but why not remove the unique constraint on `ID` and instead just make `ID` the primary key?

Comment: And don't save the password! Save a hash of it

Comment: Note that those numbers in parentheses after the INT keyword are almost entirely meaningless

Answer (score 1):

This must be the reason for the error `UNIQUE (ID(1000))`
Try this.

```
CREATE TABLE Accounts.Registry ( 
    Username VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL , 
    Password VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL , 
    First Name INT(20) NOT NULL , 
    Last Name INT(20) NOT NULL , 
    Gender INT(1) NOT NULL , 
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    PRIMARY KEY (Password, First Name, Last Name), 
    UNIQUE (ID), 
    UNIQUE (Username)) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comment and by others remove `` UNIQUE (`ID` (1000)) ``.

For better performance, create a table as`Innodb` and other useful info shared below

`Int` stores values as numbers with a range from -2147483648 to 2147483647.

`First Name` & `Last Name` change as `VARCHAR(20)`.

`Gender` you can change as `TINYINT`.

```
CREATE TABLE `Accounts`.`Registry` (
    `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Username` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    `Password` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    `First Name` INT(20) NOT NULL,
    `Last Name` INT(20) NOT NULL,
    `Gender` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    UNIQUE (`Username`)
)  ENGINE=Innodb;
```

Comment: Erm, maybe take your own advice!?!